# Regex replace quotes & less, greater then signs

Tags: javascript, regex, quotes

Im trying to find a regex to parse the following:

```
 ""username" <email@email.nl>"
```

Into:

```
username email@email.nl
```

im currently using the following to replace quotes:

```
.replace(/"/g, "")
```

How do i also replace the "< >" in the same replace function ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a *character class*:

```
.replace(/["<>]+/g, "")
```

---

In `JavaScript`:

```js
let string = ` ""username" <email@email.nl>"`;
console.log(string.replace(/["<>]+/g, ""));
```

The basic idea is to put every character or a range of characters into a class which are handled in the same way. For some - very common or often used - character ranges exist other abbreviations so that e.g. `[0-9]` is the same as `\d` or `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` is the the same as `\w` (modifiers left aside, that is).

Answer (score 0):

Here is exp to replace **" < >** 
**.replace(/[\"<>]/g, "")**